Prove the monotone property of "discretized" failure rate
Let $F$ be a cumulative distribution function for a nonnegative continuous random variable and $f$ be the corresponding probability density function. The failure rate of $F$ is then $h(t)=f(t)/(1-F(t))$, $t\geq 0$. Assume $t\mapsto h(t)$ is nondecreasing. Now I construct a discretized failure rate as follows.
Let $\lambda>0$ and $m\equiv m(\lambda)$ be an integer-valued function of $\lambda$ that satisfies $\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}m/\lambda\to\infty$. The discretized failure rate parameterized by $\lambda$ is constructed as
$$
\tilde h_\lambda(i) = \frac{F(i/\lambda)-F((i-1)/\lambda)}{1-F((i-1)/\lambda)}, \quad i=1,\ldots,m.
$$
Since $t\mapsto h(t)$ is nondecreasing, I expect $\tilde h_\lambda(i)$ constructed above is nondecreasing in $i$ when $\lambda$ is sufficiently large. That is, there exists $\lambda_0$ such that $\tilde h_\lambda(i)$ is nondecreasing in $i=1,\ldots,m(\lambda)$ for all $\lambda>\lambda_0$.
Is this true? Or do we need any regularity conditions on $F,f,h$?
